# safe deletion of dynamic 2d array

Tags: c++, pointers

If my code is the following, how can I use delete to ensure all dynamically allocated data is deleted safely?

```
float** test;
test = new float*[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    test[i] = new float[2];
```

Comment: For _every_ `new` use `delete`, for every `new[]` use `delete[]`. However, see `std::vector<std::vector<float>>`.

Comment: "**ensure** all dynamically allocated data is deleted **safely**"? Like this? https://gist.github.com/3959961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The golden rule - for each `new/new[]` you need `delete/delete[]`. So:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    delete[] test[i];
delete[] test;
```

Same as with `new/new[]`, but in reversed order.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you allocated it:

```
for( in i = 0l i < 3; i++ )
    delete[] test[i];
delete[] test;
```

Comment: This won't compile `in i = 0l`

Answer (score 1):

Just do it reversed:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    delete[] test[i];

delete[] test;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for( int i = (0); i < 3; ++i )
{
    delete[] test[i];
}
delete[] test;
```

Comment: This won't compile `in i = 0l`

Comment: Thanks, just two typos... 'l=;' and missed the 't' [@OlafDietsche]